# How to read from a certain line and write at the end of the same file using Fortran?

Tags: fortran

I have a file which looks like this:

```
 -7307.5702506795660       -13000.895251555605       -11777.655135862333       0.52503289678626652       0.51683849096298218        31.160950279498426       -7307.5698242187500       -13000.900390625000       -11777.658203125000     
  -7307.5712457548034       -13000.883260393683       -11777.647978916109       0.52714817702425010       0.84740489721298218        20.800333023071289       -7307.5698242187500       -13000.900390625000       -11777.658203125000
```

I read it with a code like this:

```
   open(1,file='my_file.txt',status='old')
   do
    read(1,*,end=10) xe,ye,ze,the,phe,enel,x0,y0,z0
    ...some mathematical calculations
   end do
10 close(1)
```

What I need to do now is add the result of my computation *at the end* of the **same file** and  continue to read my file *after the line I was calculating with*.

How can I do this in Fortran?

Comment: It is possible to do this, but are you sure that's what you want to do?  I'd suggest writing out to a separate file and then later concatenating once everything is done.  Not only will this be simpler, it saves worrying about interruption, etc.  But, if you're _sure_...

Comment: @francescalus what I am doing from the physical point of view, is considering the secondary ionizations: those number are coordinates and energy of electrons: these electrons will be propagated and will interact with matter and produce other electrons and so on...so the electron produced will be propagated too. I write those numbers on a file because I don't know from the beginnig how many electrons will be produced.

Comment: @francescalus what I meant with my comment is that I don't see another way to do it.

Comment: Another solution is to write to another file both the content of the initial file *and* the output. This way, you don't have to mess with reading and writing to the same file and you achieve the same effect. You may discard the original file afterwards if needed.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl the point of using one file is that in this way the newly added lines can be processed in the same way of the old lines

Comment: Isn't your problem one of simply reading initial conditions and then performing the simulation? Then, you can read the initial conditions in one file and write only the output? The use case is not very clear.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl The result of my calculation will become the initial condition for new calculation

Comment: I understand that. I do simulations as well, and in most situations I simply output the coordinates at regular intervals in a new file. A flow chart (or similar information) would help us to help you. Even better, a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by keeping track of the line you are on during the read. However, you need to make sure you have an emergency exit, because as the question is asked, the loop will not end until you fill your disk up.

I would also doubt this is needed. I would use an allocatable array, set it larger than you think you need, and then have a routine to check the count and adjust the size in certain chunks.

In any case, here is a fully functional example:

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer :: iunit, max
  integer :: iline
  real :: xe,ye,ze,the,phe,enel,x0,y0,z0

  iunit = 1
  max = 20

  open(iunit,file='my_file.txt',status='old')

  iline = 0
  do
     iline = iline + 1
     read(iunit,*,end=10) xe, ye, ze, the, phe, enel, x0, y0, z0

     ! call calculation(?)
     xe = xe / 1000. ! just to see a difference in the file

     call append(iunit, iline, xe, ye, ze, the, phe, enel, x0, y0, z0)

     ! bettter have this emergency exit, because file will never hit end using append
     if (iline > max) exit
  end do
10 close(iunit)

contains
  subroutine append(iunit, iline, xe, ye, ze, the, phe, enel, x0, y0, z0)
    implicit none
    integer, intent(in) :: iunit, iline
    real, intent(in) :: xe, ye, ze, the, phe, enel, x0, y0, z0

    integer :: i

    ! skip to end
    do
       read(iunit,*,end=20)
    end do
20 continue
    backspace(iunit) ! back off the EOF

    ! append to file
    write(iunit,*) xe, ye, ze, the, phe, enel, x0, y0, z0

    ! rewind file and skip to iline
    rewind(iunit)
    i = 0
    do
       i = i + 1
       read(iunit,*)
       if (i == iline) exit
    end do

  end subroutine append

end program test
```

Comment: I have tried to implement your code, but on execution I get the error: `Fortran runtime error: Sequential READ or WRITE not allowed after EOF marker, possibly use REWIND or BACKSPACE`

Comment: I testing this in Intel, which apparently allows this aberration! You need to add the statement "backspace(iunit)" just before the append write statement. I edited my answer.